# unable to load google api php client library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api-php-client

when i use APPPATH.'libraries/Google/Client.php', all the files which are included in require_once, the sub file i.e(Auth/AssertionCredentials.php)

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require_once(Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: Google/Client.php

Line Number: 18
```

Comment: You have to add base path in all google api files
  require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/' . Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php');
like in line 18

Comment: it would be very long task, because all the files of **google-api-php-client** library are interconnected with each other.

Comment: Can you not just do a find and replace? Replace "require_once "Google/" with "require_once APPPATH . "libraries/Google/"

Comment: put the snag of your folder structure and echo APPPATH

Comment: Can you post a link to the source of the google api you are using?

Comment: sure, i am using https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

Comment: Please mark the correct answer on this question.

Answer (score 16):

Copy the "Google" folder to third_party.

Create new file under application/library called google.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
set_include_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/Client.php';

class Google extends Google_Client {
    function __construct($params = array()) {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Then to use:

```
$this->load->library('google');
echo $this->google->getLibraryVersion();
```

Comment: I also needed to add: 

require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/Config.php';

Comment: It should be 
          
              require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/autoload.php';

Answer (score 2):

You can change to the libraries path, require the google client, then switch back to the CI default path..

```
    // change directory to libraries path
    chdir(APPPATH.'libraries');

    // include API
    require_once('Google/Client.php');

    // do some stuff here with the Google API

    // switch back to CI default path
    chdir(FCPATH);
```